# Faker Package, Database Seeder Issues

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, faker

I'm pretty deep down the rabbit hole on this one. This question is actually part of a bigger question related to getting my Laravel app to function correctly. Here's the link to the other question if you'd like to see more about my troubles: [Model, Database Error in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476146/wrongful-modelnotfoundexception-in-laravel).

So, now I'm trying to use the database seeder package, Faker, to populate my database. I've installed it correctly, but I'm having trouble making it work for me beyond the User table. Here's what I've got for my UserTableSeeder:

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

  public function run()
  {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
    {
        User::create(
            [
                'id' => $faker->randomDigit,
                'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
                'email' => $faker->freeEmail,
                'notify' => $faker->randomElement($array = ['y', 'n']),
                'created_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),
                'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now')
            ]
        );
    }
  }
}
```

This is half-working when I run `php artisan db:seed`; it creates only a dozen rows or so. My users table has seven columns:

id (its type is integer),
first_name(varchar),
last_name(varchar),
email(varchar),
notify(enum),
created_at(timestamp),
and updated_at(timestamp)

Any code that would handle this correctly or serve as a template for a similar table would be greatly appreciated. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'id' => $faker->randomDigit` is likely causing conflicting IDs (I'd bet you get ten rows, not a dozen, as there are ten possible digits). Try `$faker->randomNumber` instead.

Comment: I had to run `php artisan db:seed` a few times, but that solution has worked. I've got three more tables that need populating, so I'll probably be returning to this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Migration: $table->increments('id');

Having this you don't need to set any value on the ID and you will avoid the id collision